# How to implement TopBar in a Cocoa Application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstoolbar, nsstatusbar

I am new in Cocoa development. I want to implement this type of Bar (below image) in my application. How can i implement this? Which control using for this ?                   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read *Mac OS X Human Interface Guidelines*. The section relevant to your question is [Designing a Toolbar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-BABIFCFJ), but it would be a good idea to read the entire document. It contains a lot of important information about the various user interface components, how to use them, and links to additional documentation on each component.

Answer (score 2):

Start with some sample code related to `NSToolbar`.